# How to insert current data into database on submit button click?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Im trying to find a way to insert the current user id and cursuscode into my DB but they way i'm trying is it hasn't been an succes yet. If someone click on the submit button I would like to push it into the database but when i click on the button nothing happens. Thats why i think the query is not right/syntax is wrong or my way of using the post method is wrong.

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('includes/mysql_config.php');

$id = isset($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] : header('location: login.php');
$Cursist = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT id FROM Cursist WHERE id =".$_SESSION['id']) || false;
if(!$Cursist){
  header('location: login.php');
}
require_once('./header.php');

$cursusCode = $_GET['cursusCode'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cursus WHERE cursusCode = $cursusCode";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
$amount = mysqli_affected_rows($con);

for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
  $cursus = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>

     <?php
      if(isset( $_POST['submit'] )){
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO cursistCode (Cursus_cursusCode, Cursist_id) VALUES ($cursusCode, $Cursist)";
             $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        }?>
<header>
</header>

<?php require_once('./navigation.php'); ?>
<!-- Post Content -->
<article>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
          <div class="post-preview">
              <?php echo $cursus['description'] . "<br />";?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
              <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
      <form method="post" name="myform">
        <input type="submit" value="Schrijf je in" name="submit">
      </form>
      Cursussoort:
      <?php echo $cursus['type'] . "<br />";?>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
 <?php } ?>
<hr>
<?php require_once('./footer.php'); ?>
```

What is it that im doing wrong since as far I can tell this should be fine. My database structure is like this:

Cursist 
id (pk) links to Cursist_id in table cursistCode (one to many)

- name
- password
- not used info in this query

cursistCode

- Cursus_cursusCode
- cursist_id

cursus

- id (pk) links to Cursus_cursusCode
- not used info in this query

my guest would be i did something wrong here:

```
  if(isset( $_POST['submit'] )){
    $SQL = "INSERT INTO cursistCode (Cursus_cursusCode, Cursist_id) VALUES ($cursusCode, $Cursist)";
         $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    }?>
```

I hope this will be enough information to help me out if i missed some crical info tell me.

Comment: First of all, Move your `INSERT` logic on top, you have no reason to do this in the middle of the page display. Then,I see a `<?php } ?>` on the middle of your form that has no reason to be there, It closes your `for` loop not where it should.

Comment: @ThomasG Made some changes like you told me if i understood it right

Comment: Thats better, now you can add a print of your SQL statement just before the`$result = mysql_query($SQL);` in order to see if it enters the condition and if the SQL is correct

Comment: Hmm looks like the button is not responding at all, when I press the button with the print nothing happens.

Comment: Still on mobile... I'll look better at your code later on a PC. You can still move a print at the top of the page to see if its reloaded after the submit, if not add an `action="thepage.php"` in your `<form>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are   really a lot of issues with your code...

TO begin with the most dangerous:

```
$cursusCode = $_GET['cursusCode'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM cursus WHERE cursusCode = $cursusCode";
```

This is a **SQL injection** invitation. You should at best use a parametrized query, at least a `mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cursusCode'])`

Then, you take the **cursusCode** var from a `GET`, and you retrieve from your DB all cursus having this cursus code.

It appears from what you are doing next that you might have several cursus with the same cursuscode in your DB. 
It sounds strange to me as you said thats cursusCode is a PK in your cursus table.
Once you have the number of cursus retrieved, you start a loop for each cursus .

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $amount; $i++) {
  $cursus = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
```

2 possibilities:

- If you only have one cursus, you should not do a loop.
- If you can have several cursus, we have a lot of mistakes  :

  1. Your INSERT instruction has nothing to do in that loop, with the way you are doing, if you have several cursus, you will make an INSERT for each of them, while your goal seems to only to register the subscription of one user to one cursus. **Move this logic before the loop**, even if you can only have one cursus.
  2. you add your `navigation.php` and `<header>` in the loop, which will result in several navigation bars
  3. if you have several cursus, you should add a post variable to know on which cursus submit button the user as clicked

Then, your form as no `action=""`

Without action the form should be submitted to itself. That might be OK but that might also be a potential issue.

I would advise you to fix all this, and after that if it still  doesn't work, you should simply add `echo` statements everywhere to understand what happens.

Comment: Thanks, ill try to do this all in the evening since I'm not able to do it now.